# Ajax Post Data Form without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Firstly, I've been stuck between **method** and **type** as if I've defined  method in form so I don't have to define it in ajax, and if so? ajax gives **undefined** in console.

Secondly, The following code gives **405 POST method not allowed**.

Also, When I do succeed trying bunch of things ajax refreshes the whole page, I want to post data to server without refreshing the page.

Any help would do!!

**Controller Function**

```
public function storeDevSkill(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $this->validate($request,
        [
            'dev_skill_name' => 'required',
            'dev_skill_exp' => 'required',
        ]);

    try {
        $data = array(
            'dev_id' => $user_id,
            'dev_skill_name' => $request->dev_skill_name,
            'dev_skill_exp' => $request->dev_skill_exp,
        );
        DevSkill::create($data);
        return back();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return back()->withError($exception->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
    Route::post('/developer/create/skill/{user_id}', 'SuperAdminControllers\DeveloperController@storeDevSkill')->name('store.developer.skill');
```

**Form:**

```
<form id="form_skill" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action= "{{route('store.developer.skill',$user->user_id)}}">
```

**Button:**

```
<button type="submit" id="addskillSubmit" value="{{$user->user_id}}" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form_skill').on('submit', function (event) {
            console.log("Ajax Call")
            event.preventDefault();
            var action_url = '';
            var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
            console.log(action_url)

            $.ajax({
                url: action_url,
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                // dataType: 'json',

                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        console.log('Ajax Success')
                    } else {
                        // var table = $('#addskilltable').DataTable();
                        // table.ajax.reload();
                        console.log(response.success)
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is your `action_url` an empty string? You need to pass the URL in ajax url property, not in the form.

Comment: Because I've passed the url in form, and bind data to form submit.

Comment: I thinks action_url is incorrect

Comment: @ShariqShaikh this is not how ajax url works. you'll need to pass your `route url` inside ajax  `url: '/developer/create/skill/'`

Comment: like the others say as well `action_url` is empty and you don't pass anything. You make a post request to nowhere.
If you have the `action_url` in your form, the line `var action_url = '';` will replace it

Comment: But it did work when I bind it to the route i've passed in the form.
Let me try it by passing the url to action_url.

Comment: You need to pass that action to your call - jQuery won’t know on its own what to call based on the fact that you have it on the form tag. Use url: $this.attr(‘action’) to get it. Reason why you get method error and reload is because it makes call to the current page, which is evidently not accepting post method.

Comment: `var user_id = $("#addskillSubmit").attr('value');`
                `var action_url = '/developer/create/skill' +'/'+ user_id;`

It still gives undefined in the console.

Comment: Best thing would be to open `Developer tools` of your browser and check in the Network Tab, what is sent where when you send your form.

Comment: Yes, indeed I use developer tools. Anyway, Thanks alot guys.It turns out that I was passing the empty string in action_url. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Just a little help with reloading the table in ajax success:function. :X

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `action` attribute from the form to your ajax call like so

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form_skill').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (response) {
          if (response.error) {
            console.log('Ajax Success')
          } else {
            console.log(response.success)
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Give it a try and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on('submit', '#form_skill', function(e){

```
e.preventDefault();

var nFormId = '#'+ $(this).attr('id');
var formData = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr('action');
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: formData,
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $(nFormId)[0].reset();
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

          },
          beforeSend: function () {

          },
          complete: function () {

        }
});
```

});

Hope this answer help you.